# Error while sending email in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, message

I m using `SKPSMTPMessage` files to send the mails but it is showing the following error while sending the email

```
 Error Domain=SKPSMTPMessageError 
 Code=535 "Invalid username or password." 
 UserInfo=0xaa2de20 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Go to Email Preferences in the application and re-enter your username and password., 
                     NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid username or password.}
```

Where should I change the user name and password? The code is as follows:

```
SKPSMTPMessage *msg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
msg.fromEmail = @"123456789s@gmail.com";
msg.toEmail = to;
msg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
msg.requiresAuth = YES;
msg.login = @"123456789@gmail.com";
msg.pass = @"123456789//";
msg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
msg.subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check Out %@ by Docstoc", self.navigationItem.title];
msg.delegate = self;

NSMutableArray *msg_parts = [NSMutableArray array];

NSDictionary *plain_text_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"text/html\r\n\tcharset=UTF-8;\r\n\tformat=flowed", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                 [message stringByAppendingString:@"\n"], kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,                                         
                                 nil];
[msg_parts addObject:plain_text_part];
msg.parts = msg_parts;

[msg send];
```

Note: This is perfectly working code. Since last week it is showing the error.

Comment: Did you login to your Email app in iPhone?

Comment: yes i did but still it is showing an error

Comment: Just a tip: Do not use your real password or if you have did it in the code above, change it ASAP. ;)

Comment: You probably have the wrong user ID or password.

Answer (score 0):

try

`NSMutableArray` *msg_parts = [[`NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray`:array];

instead of NSMutableArray *msg_parts = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 0):

Please check your  below details are valid or not,

```
msg.login = @"123456789@gmail.com";
msg.pass = @"123456789//";
```